# Check if item exists in database by field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a class called `Product` and I want to check if there is already a product in the database with the same title.

```
class Product(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  ...


for (something in something):
  check if db contains product with a title of 'Some Product'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`.exists()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists):

```
Product.objects.filter(title='Some Product').exists()
```

It might however be better to enforce uniqness at the database level, with [**`unique=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

then if the database enforces (most databases do), it will simply be impossible to create a new `Product` with the same `title`.

You can also obtain a `Product`, or create it if it does not yet exists, with [**`.get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
my_prod, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(title='Some Product')
```